# Is there a trick for adding and subtracting binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, arithmetic

I had a problem for which I needed to evaluate:
$$\sum_{n=1}^3{5\choose n}$$
I understand the basic concept of binomial coefficients, but I haven't been able to find an easy way to evaluate this by hand simply based on the numbers involved. Is there a trick I can use for adding and subtracting binomial coefficients so I don't have to use Wolfram Alpha every time I want to do something similar?

Edit: I cannot evaluate coefficients myself. That's why I'm looking for a trick to add using only the numbers displayed.

Comment: Note:  $$\binom52=\binom53$$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner How do you know that from looking at them?

Comment: A basic equality is ${n \choose r}={n \choose n-r}$

Comment: @RossMillikan I did not see that. That is helpful.

Comment: They’re both $\dfrac {5!}{2!3!}$

Comment: You need ${n \choose r}=\frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.  If you haven't found that you haven't done your research.  That underlies the basic equality of my last comment.  I wish I could -1 again.  You can plug $n=5, r=2$ into that and get $10$.  The Wikipedia link I gave you has that formula.

Comment: @RossMillikan I told you I already know that formula, I just didn't notice that ${n \choose r}={n \choose n-r}$. Should I just delete the question or what?

Answer (score 1):

$5 \choose 1$ is just $5$.  There are two more terms in the sum.  Can you evaluate ${5 \choose 2}$ and $5 \choose 3$?.  Hint:  they are equal.  Then just add them up.

Comment: I don't know how to evaluate the coefficient, but yes, I know the first is just 5. Edited.

Comment: @MicahWindsor: $$\binom{n}k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k!}$$

Comment: Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) or something about binomial coefficients?  Have you seen Pascal's triangle?  What do you know about this?

Comment: I have done my research, I know the formula, I'm just wondering if there's an *easier* , faster way.

Comment: For the problem you posted, no, there is not an easier way except to note the equality of the other two.  For similar problems, it depends on the definition of similar.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\binom{m}{n+1}}{\binom{m}{n}}
&=\frac{\frac{m!}{(n+1)!(m-n-1)!}}{\frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}}\\
&=\frac{m!n!(m-n)!}{m!(n+1)!(m-n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{m-n}{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

we have
$\binom{m}{n+1}
=\frac{m-n}{n+1}\binom{m}{n}
$.

Starting with
$\binom{m}{0}
=1$
we get

$n=0,
\binom{m}{1}
=\frac{m}{1}\binom{m}{0}
=m
$,

$n=1,
\binom{m}{2}
=\frac{m-1}{2}\binom{m}{1}
=\frac{m-1}{2}m
=\frac{m(m-1)}{2}
$,

$n=2,
\binom{m}{3}
=\frac{m-2}{3}\binom{m}{2}
=\frac{m-2}{3}\frac{m(m-1)}{2}
=\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)}{6}
$,

and so on.

At each stage,
the fraction you
multiply by
has its numerator decreased
and denominator increased.